# Golang return or float or complex

Tags: go, complex-numbers

I'm trying to write a cubic equation solver.

```
func (a,b,c,d float64) (returnType,err){
      
   if a<0{
     return complex, nil
   }
   if a>=0 {
     return float64, nil
   }
}
```

Is there a way to return and interface or something to manage this behavior?

Answer (score 6):

Since real numbers (floats) are a subset of complex numbers, you may opt to always return a complex number, and where you would only return `float64`, you leave the imaginary part `0`:

```
func abcd(a, b, c, d float64) (complex128, error) {
    if a < 0 {
        r, j := 1.0, 2.0
        return complex(r, j), nil
    }
    if a >= 0 {
        r := 3.0
        return complex(r, 0), nil
    }
    return 0 + 0i, nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
c, err := abcd(1, 0, 0, 0)
fmt.Println(c, err)
if imag(c) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("\treal:", real(c))
}

c, err = abcd(-1, 0, 0, 0)
fmt.Println(c, err)
if imag(c) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("\treal:", real(c))
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TqHsH2vPet1)):

```
(3+0i) <nil>
    real: 3
(1+2i) <nil>
```

Yes, if a complex number would be returned whose imaginary part is `0`, you can't distinguish this special case from the case where only a real number would be returned. Maybe you don't have to? If not, it's not a problem. If you do need to differentiate them, you may also return a 3rd value telling if the result is in fact a complex number:

```
func abcd(a, b, c, d float64) (x complex128, isComplex bool, err error) {
    if a < 0 {
        r, j := 1.0, 2.0
        return complex(r, j), true, nil
    }
    if a >= 0 {
        r := 3.0
        return complex(r, 0), false, nil
    }
    return 0 + 0i, false, nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
c, isC, err := abcd(1, 0, 0, 0)
fmt.Println(c, isC, err)
if !isC {
    fmt.Println("\treal:", real(c))
}

c, isC, err = abcd(-1, 0, 0, 0)
fmt.Println(c, err)
if !isC {
    fmt.Println("\treal:", real(c))
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cfGkv6cpqq_C).

The above solutions are possible because real numbers are a subset of complex numbers. In the general case you may use multiple return values, each being a pointer, and you may check which return value is not `nil`. Something like this:

```
func abcd(a, b, c, d float64) (*complex128, *float64, error) {
    if a < 0 {
        r, j := 1.0, 2.0
        x = :complex(r, j)
        return &x, nil, nil
    }
    if a >= 0 {
        f := 3.0
        return nil, &f, nil
    }
    return nil, nil, nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
c, f, err := abcd(1, 0, 0, 0)
fmt.Println(c, f, err)
if c != nil {
    fmt.Println("\tcmplx:", *c)
}
if f != nil {
    fmt.Println("\treal:", *f)
}

c, f, err = abcd(-1, 0, 0, 0)
fmt.Println(c, f, err)
if c != nil {
    fmt.Println("\tcmplx:", *c)
}
if f != nil {
    fmt.Println("\treal:", *f)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/amePERznuiJ)):

```
<nil> 0xc000018050 <nil>
    real: 3
0xc000018070 <nil> <nil>
    cmplx: (1+2i)
```

And  you could also combine the last 2 solutions: you could return non-pointers and an `isComplex` flag telling which return value is valid.